# Optimal ordering of rows/columns to reduce size of R data.frame object

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization

Is there a good method or algorithm to determine the optimal ordering and arrangement of rows and columns to minimize the file size of an R data.frame on disk?

Consider the following data:

```
# Init
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)
n_rows <- 10e6

df_1 <- data.frame(
    V1 = sample(1:10, n_rows, replace=TRUE),
    V2 = sample(1:2, n_rows, replace=TRUE),
    V3 = sample(1:100, n_rows, replace=TRUE),
    V4 = sample(1:1000, n_rows, replace=TRUE),
    V5 = sample(1:5, n_rows, replace=TRUE)
) %>% as_data_frame()

df_2 <- df_1 %>% arrange(
    V2,    V5,    V1,    V3,    V4
)

df_3 <- df_2 %>% select(
    V2,    V5,    V1,    V3,    V4
)

saveRDS(df_1, "temp_1.RDS")
saveRDS(df_2, "temp_2.RDS")
saveRDS(df_3, "temp_3.RDS")
```

The output file sizes are:

- df_1 / temp_1.RDS = 43,770 KB
- df_2 / temp_2.RDS = 10,091 KB
- df_3 / temp_3.RDS = 10,089 KB

In this setting, we observe a dramatic reduction in file size by ordering the rows in a reasonable way, and a tiny reduction by ordering the columns in 'some' way after arranging the rows.

Is there an automatic way of working out the best order of columns and the best order to arrange them in? The approach probably uses dynamic programming or something, but I'm hoping there's an R package out there which has a ready to use implementation.

Once loaded in memory, are the pre-arranged objects generally more performant? I'm guessing 'yes' for doing things that are aligned with that pre-arranged grouping.

EDIT, out of interest, here's some timing results for a simple task:

```
# Do a process on a data.frame
process_func <- function(x){
    x %>% group_by(
        V2,V5,V1
    ) %>% summarise(
        sum(V4),
        sum(V3)
    )
}

system.time(replicate(100, process_func(df_1)))
system.time(replicate(100, process_func(df_2)))
system.time(replicate(100, process_func(df_3)))
```

The same task takes (repeated 100 times):

- 95 seconds on df_1
- 47 seconds on df_2
- 48 seconds on df_3

Comment: by default, `saveRDS` has `compress = TRUE`. If your question is specific to that way of storing data to disk (which I assume because else it is too general), then basically you are asking how compression works (and yes, of course that will benefit from ordering)

Comment: I'm aware the .rds files are compressed, but is there a way to determine the optimal arrangement without trial and error? Or even a good heuristic?

Answer (score 2):

As a good heuristic, I would order by the columns with less distinct values first. More optimal solutions would require much more computation time, which would be difficult considering the size of your problem.

You can do:

```
df_4 <- df_1 %>% 
  arrange_at(., names(sort(sapply(., n_distinct))))
```

Comment: I imagine this probably works reasonable well in most cases. Although, I had assumed surely some comp sci, database, etc researcher has looked in to the maximum compressibilty of a dataset.